# Does "space" require an article?

Tags: grammar, articles, countability

We use "the" when there is only one of something. There's only one space. Therefore we have to say:

> There are millions of stars in **the space**.

But I've seen that "space" is used without article. What is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Space*** isn't just about *that* space. We use the term *space* for the area beyond our atmosphere as a case of its more general usage. We're not talking about its specialised meaning in physics; that's beside the point. Just its general, everyday usage:

> I love this apartment, it's got loads of **space**.

Space is the gap between objects, not occupied by anything else. **Outer space** is usually the space between our atmosphere and anything else, and that's what we mean by *space* when we talk about *space exploration* and similar.

Now, when we talk about a *very* specific space, it becomes countable:

> The **space** between the fridge and the cooker

But, by convention if not by logic (the logic depends who you ask), *space* beyond our atmosphere is more of an abstract concept, and certainly not specific. It is thus uncountable and does not take an article. It then handily looks the same as the concept of *space* in physics, leading to people conflating the two inappropriately, but we can live with that.